# Linear GAM in python

Tags: python, spline, gam, pygam

I need to copy this plot using pygam library.
[image]
I create GAM using the following code:

```
gam = LinearGAM(s(0, n_splines=5, spline_order=4) + s(1, n_splines=9) + f(2))
gam = gam.gridsearch(X, y, lam = lams)
```

Unfortunately, in my case the plots are the following:
[image]
The issue that I cannot manage to make the polygonal line in the left graph.
**Note**
This two graphs should be **natural** splines.